# How to do self injection Spring Boot 3+, in order to pass through proxy and apply transactional behavior

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-transactions

I'd like to create a self reference in my service so that I can use it to go through Spring's proxy and apply transactional behavior.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service {
  @Lazy private final Service self;

  public void foo() {
    self.bar();
  }

  @Transactional
  public void bar() {
    // do some transactional stuff
  }
}
```

I want to do that also to be compliant with `java:S6809`

```
A method annotated with Spring’s @Async or @Transactional annotations will not work as expected if invoked directly from within its class.
This is because Spring generates a proxy class with wrapper code to manage the method’s asynchronicity (@Async) or to handle the transaction (@Transactional). However, when called using this, the proxy instance is bypassed, and the method is invoked directly without the required wrapper code.
```

The issue is that I cannot do it otherwise I get an error on startup

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

- I used `@Lazy`
- I used `lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy` in `lombok.config`

Is setting `spring.main.allow-circular-references` to true the only solution to do self-injection in Spring?

(some references: https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-transactional-mistakes-everyone-did-31418e5a6d6b)

Comment: This will only work with field injection, not constructor injected. Remove `final` and add `@Autowired` next to `@Lazy`.

Comment: I actually also struggled with field injection . Also field injection is not recommended but I guess it's better than allowing circular references in properties.

Comment: Correct it isn't recommended, but the same can be said for self-injection as it is more of workaround than an actual solution. The real solution would be to have proper transactional boundaries. Another option is to inject `ObjectProvider<Service>` and then do a lookup whenever you need to do the self invocation (yet another workaround but one that doesn't require field injection or allowing circular references).

Comment: I agree. I ended up reworking the way my business code was organized in order to call the transactional methods from another service. Doing it this way, I made sure that the called service was in charge for handling the transaction. The other service method was non transactional and therefore delegated everything to the called one regarding transactions. That ObjectProvider thing is definitely something to look after. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `TransactionTemplate` instead of `@Transactional`

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyService {
    @Lazy
    private final MyService self;
    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;


    public void foo() {
        self.bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
        transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(ts -> {
            // do tx stuff
        });
    }
}
```

see
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/programmatic.html